# Session key is null in facebook app

Tags: facebook, session

I have created facebook object with api and secret key. My application is on php. When I am trying to print the facebook object. The {session_key} value is null. My code is as follows:-

```
    include_once 'client/facebook.php';
    $api_key = "ENTER YOUR API KEY HERE";
    $secret = "ENTER YOUR SECRET HERE";

    $facebook = new Facebook( $api_key, $secret,true );
    echo "<pre>";
    print_R($facebook);
```

When the facebook object is printed. The {session_key} is null. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
    if ($session) {
  echo $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
echo  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```